# How do you set an Optional parameter with a global variable on a Function defined in a Package

Tags: syntax, pattern-matching

In a Package I am writing, I'm trying to define a function with an [`Optional`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Optional.html) parameter in it that is set to a global variable.

```
PlotIndex[IndexLoopPlotMtx_:IndexLoopPlot]:=ListPlot[.....
```

However, the `Optional` value `IndexLoopPlot` is not set until after the package is loaded and other functions are run. Therefore `PlotIndex` is read in as,

```
PlotIndex[IndexLoopPlotMtx_:{}]:=ListPlot[.....
```

In other words, `IndexLoopPlotMtx` is set to `Null`, and when the function is run later it tries to `plot {}` instead of the matrix `IndexLoopPlot`. Is there a way to get it delay setting the `Default` until the function is called for the first time from the package?

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to point to the global variable using its full context path as `` Global`IndexLoopPlot ``. Otherwise, the optional variable will be interpreted as `` YourPackage`IndexLoopPlot ``. The following example shows how:

```
Quiet@Remove[a, "test`*"];
BeginPackage["test`"];
f[x_: Global`a] := {x}
EndPackage[];
```

[image]